# Backbone.js - Get object of Model error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to learn backbone.js and I try simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src="my4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function($){
    var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function(){
            return {
                author: 'chalist',
                status: 'test'
            }
        }
    });
    var tweet = new Tweet();
    console.log(tweet.get('status'));

})(jQuery);
```

I get in console.log: **undefined**

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Works for me if i put it in a jsfiddle and run it. (Outputs test to the console)

Comment: @homtg I found it. **defaults**  is not a function

Comment: @chalist `defaults` could be a function! Maybe you are using a very old backbone and/or underscore

Comment: @KiTO is right, you're using an older version of Backbone. `defaults` has been able to be a function since AFAIK 0.9.X

Comment: @KiTO http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults

Comment: @chalist So what's the problem? from that page : "Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances. **Instead, define defaults as a function**."

Comment: @KiTO sure, but when I use function for return value nothing passes but when I use object is no problem

Comment: Which version of Backbone you are using? Your code works with Backbone-V1.0.0 (tested)

Comment: And what version of underscore you are using?